# excel vba - sumif and average by id field

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to excel [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), was looking for a way to calculate the following:

Have id field in `column A` in text format. Based on each ID field and where Text field is not empty, i want to set the Pos field at value `1` (at the start of each new ID) and then increment to `2` at the next text field position which is not empty.

The id should reset to `1` when the id in column A changes and then increment and so on.

Also the Final Sc should be calculated for each Pos as simple average of Sc between 2 positions and printed at the beginning of each POS.

> eg. for ID 12534, for Pos 1, Final Sc should be (0.2+0.3)/2.

[image]

Comment: Hey, have you tried to do any coding so far? If so, please post it here. Afterall, stackoverflow is to help you with your code, not to do the coding for you, for free :)

Comment: i am kind of newbie, i would have posted the code if i knew how to :) if you cant help, thats fine. was just asking a qn. no worries. thanks!

Comment: Are new IDs always separated by an empty cell?

Comment: Yes they are always separated by an empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, presuming your table starts at cell `A1`

```
Private Sub fill_pos()

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace Sheet1 with your Sheetname 
  Dim lr As Long: lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last active row in column A
  Dim pos As Integer: pos = 0
  Dim avgcounter As Integer: avgcounter = 0 ' counter for average amount division
  Dim avgsum As Double: avgsum = 0 ' counter for sc
  Dim textrowpos As Long: textrowpos = 0 ' to keep track when to write finalsc
  Dim firstloop As Boolean: firstloop = True ' need to check for first loop, _
  because we cant get average withotu collecting data first

  For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lr) ' for each cell in userrange
      If IsEmpty(cell) Then
          pos = 0 ' new id, reset pos
      Else
          If Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(, 1)) Then ' text found,
              pos = pos + 1
              cell.Offset(, 3) = pos ' update pos
              If Not firstloop Then
                  Cells(textrowpos, 5) = avgsum / avgcounter 
                  'got already data collected (since its not first loop), can write result
              End If
              firstloop = False ' toggle firstloop off
              avgsum = 0 ' reset all counters
              avgcounter = 0
              textrowpos = cell.Row ' save the row position to update future result
          Else
              If Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(, 2)) Then
                  avgsum = avgsum + cell.Offset(, 2) ' add them to average
                  avgcounter = avgcounter + 1
              End If
          End If
      End If

      If (cell.Row = lr) Then
          Cells(textrowpos, 5) = avgsum / avgcounter 
          ' since list ends with empty cell, we need to update textrow pos one last time
      End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Yields the desired result:

[image]

But I highly doubt you'll understand the code without doing some coding yourself.
*Honestly I genuinely contemplated whether I should even post the answer..*

Comment: Thank  you! it works! i am newbie in excel vba with one of a kind use case. Sorry i understand your concern that i did not attempt to code, i am reading some material on the vba content but i dint know where to start or how to approach the problem statement. Again, thanks for your quick help!

Comment: Well, glad you're at least putting the effort in. Either way, if this solved your question, please mark it as the answer (with the checkmark sign) and also upvote @chillin 's answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: il read through your code and try to understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in VBA (of course), but here's a formula approach if you want to try it.

Try putting this formula in cell D2 (assuming `Pos` is in column D):

```
=IF($B2<>"",COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"),"")
```

And this formula in cell E2 (assuming `Final Sc` is in column E):

```
=IF($D2=1,AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,$A2),"")
```

And then drag/fill the formulas down to the last row of your data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SpecialCells()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) method and [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas) property of `Range` object:

```
Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim iArea As Long

    With Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each area In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            With area.Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count
                    .Areas(iArea).Offset(-1, 2).Resize(1).Value = iArea
                    .Areas(iArea).Offset(-1, 3).Resize(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Areas(iArea).Offset(, 1))
                Next
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```